# How to find a basis of eigenvectors??

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

DISCLAIMER ! THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE OF MY OTHER QUESTIONS. THE QUESTION I AM ASKING NOW ONLY TAKES INTO CONSIDERATION THE SAME MATRIX I HAVE USED IN OTHER QUESTIONS. THAT'S IT.

So i have this matrix

A= $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -2 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 1 & -6 \\
    0 & 0 & -2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

We compute the characteristic polynomial

p(λ) = det(A − λId) = (λ + 2)²· (1 − λ)

which gives me two roots namely λ1 = −2 of multiplicity 2, and λ2 = 1 of multiplicity 1.

First of all , I  solve the homogeneous system associated with A + 2Id which gives us

Nul(A+2Id)=Span $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & -1  \\
    0 & 1  \\
    1 & 0  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

I know how to solve the system associated with A+2Id since the matrix i get by doing (A+2Id) is pretty simple (there are two 0 rows) and the homogeneous equation associated with it is x+y-2z=0

However my confusion arises when , in order to find a basis of eigenvectors, I need to compute E(λ2), so we need to solve the homogeneous system associated with(A − Id).

I do not now how to go on from here.

Computing A-Id (please correct me if im wrong, since A-1(Id)=A-Id), gives me the matrix

A-Id= $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -3 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 0 & -6 \\
    0 & 0 & -3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

How do i proceed from here? On the answers sheet it says that Nul(A − Id) = Span (column vector)= (0,1,0).

Should i compute the characteristic polynomial of the (A-Id) matrix? How do i do that ? Is that the right way to do that?

Please if anybody can show me some simple and clear steps on how to get

Nul(A − Id) = Span (column vector)= (0,1,0) and tell me if what I'm doing is right! Thanks!

Comment: You calculated $A-I$ incorrectly.

Comment: How come ? where did i do it wrong

Comment: Come on now! I mean really - figuring out $A-I$ is not that hard. Do the subtraction again, carefully; what you get is not what you say $A-I$ is above.

Comment: I did it again . On the second row i still got -6, but the user below got 6?

Comment: This is pathetic. What did you get when you did it again?

Comment: Im sorry .... -6-0 gives you 6?

Comment: I got all the same numbersas the user below other than 6. According to what i have ALWAYS studied, -6-0 is still -6 and not 6 .

Comment: Im really trying to understand what i'm doing wrong. I just dont get it and having a form of dyscalculia doesn't certainly help.

Comment: All the same numbers as below except for $-6$ is right. Now **look at** what you wrote in the question! It's _not_ "all the samme numbers as below except for $-6$."

Comment: It seems you found the error, as you just edited it away.

Comment: Right. $1-1\ne1$. You're welcome...

Comment: Thank you !!!!!

Comment: Doing this i got that x=0 and z=0. Now im having problems with y . Since y, on the second equation is depicted as 0, does that mean that it is a free variable (y=1) and i should write the basis as (0,1,0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  put $A-I$ in reduced row echelon form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-3&0&0\\3&0&-6\\0&0&-3\end{pmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&0&-2\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&-2\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
so we have the equations
$$x=0,\quad z=0.$$

Comment: Thanks ! What if i try to to it like this. From the matrix (A-Id) i can directly see that x=0 and z=0. This leaves me with the second row being 3(0)+y-6(0)=0. How do i solve for y which gives me as a  y basis 1?

Comment: Shouldn't it be -6 on the second row? (-6-0)=-6

Comment: You're right – a mistyping. I'll fix that.

Comment: Since y on the second equation is mutliplied by 0, can i say that it is a free variable as so equate it to 1?

Comment: You're absolutely right.

Comment: Thank you !! You're great :)